# No command function

Tags: shell, unix

I have made two files. Both files might have or have not output based on the availability of input[I have made a conditional code in between them which totally prevents from their formation when there is no input in them]. So eventually, if any of them do not have any input, they are not formed.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
[[  -f "$file1" && -f "$file2" ]] || exit 1
paste "$file1" "$file2"
```

or, just run the `paste`, and redirect the error message and exit if unsuccessful.

```
paste "$file1" "$file2" 2>/dev/null || exit 1
```

Comment: @reader if you don't need anymore the `$file1` and the `$file2` just remove them _after_ the paste, so they will not exists in the next run... Or move them away... or just change the filenames...

Comment: @reader also, you should read the [tour] and [help]. One problem = one question. Another problem = another question.